# quiescent stage (G0) occurs at the end of M phase or G1 phase:

Tags: cell-biology, cell-cycle

I know that G0 phase occurs when certain cells exit the cell cycle during G1 phase but that means it goes to G0 phase after M phase right?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE.Biology! It is often helpful to do a little internet research such as e.g. googling your question.

I googled it and it gave me [this image](http://www.opentextbooks.org.hk/ditatopic/34762), which tells me that G0 cells leave from and re-enter G1 phase.